# Read text file from inside Java eclipse executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to read a text file from inside of exectutable jar. I can read it from eclipse, but can not from executable jar.I googled, and found out I have to use getClass.getResource. But all google examples are not for Buffered Reader.
My current codes are the following.

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try
{
File file = new File ("tfl.txt");
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new    
FileInputStream(file),"unicode"));
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
InputStream localInputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource_name");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(localInputStream));
```

Comment: The text file is unicode. How to change your code to read unicode file?

Comment: you can pass an encoding as the second parameter to `InputStreamReader`. Try passing it `"utf-8"`